# parameter error when inheriting from tkinter object

Tags: python, class, inheritance, tkinter

I have a class, call it `Test`, which has a variable `var`. It uses this variable in its `__init__` mathod, and maybe looks something like this:

```
class Test(object):
    var = 0
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.var)
```

In order to change this variable before I initialise the class, this seemed logical

```
test = Test
test.var = 42
test.__init__(test)
```

...and behaves like I expected it to. (printing `42`)
However, when the code looks like this:

```
class Test(Canvas):
    var = 0
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Canvas.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        print(self.var)

test = Test
test.var = 42
test.__init__(test, frame) #tkinter frame I had made elsewhere
```

... it throws an error at the `canvas.__init__` line, complaining that

```
TypeError: _options() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cnf'
```

I doubt this is a problem with the cnf parameters, as the class works fine when called 'normally', as in `test = Test()`. I have a feeling the parameters are being passed differently.
Can someone shed some light?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you think `test = Test` does? It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Why are you calling `__int__`? That is highly unusual.

Comment: I wanted to change the the class' variable before I initialised the class, like in the first example. Is this bad practise? In which case, what is a better way of doing it?

Comment: The first variable ("self") must be an instance of a class, not the class itself. ie the result of `Test()` or `test()`. And when you create the instance, `__init__()` is called automatically, so you don't need that anyway.

Comment: @Jonathan " when you create the instance" do you mean the `test = Test`? Because nothing is printed there (else it would have printed `0`, not `42`), so I assumed `__init__` wasn't being called...

Comment: Hmm, so do you think this is the wrong approach, or is there some way of getting around it? @Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how python classes work.

In your code you're doing `test = Test`, which does nothing but make `test` point to the class `Test`. It does *not* create an instance of `Test`.

If you want to change the value of a class value, there's no need to do an assignment to a temporary variable first. For example. to create a class that has `var` set to zero, and you later want to change it to 42, you can do it this way:

```
class Test(object):
    var = 0
...
Test.var = 42
```

Also, you should never call `__init__` directly, except perhaps when calling the function of the superclass with the `__init__` of a subclass. Instead, you create an instance of the class which will automatically call the `__init__` for you:

```
test = Test()
```

This all works the same whether you inherit from a tkinter class or any other class.

When you run the following example, it will print out `42`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Test(tk.Canvas):
    var = 0
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack()
        print(self.var)

Test.var = 42

root = tk.Tk()
test = Test(root)
```

Note that because this is a class variable, changing it once will change it for all instances.

Comment: Thank you Bryan! Yes, this was what was confusing me; I did not realise that I could change the variable before I had created the instance. Helpful answer!

Comment: @EriktheRed: the code in your question changes the variable before creating an instance. Your code does not create an instance anywhere.